# How can I iterate through all the ports of a switch and disable them one by one using python and ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, san

I am wondering how I can iterate through 48 ports of a SAN switch one by one and enable or disable them ? For some background info, I write python scripts for work to automate the testing of networking devices. I use a library called paramiko which connects to these devices using SSH.

Here is a simple function I wrote in where a user enters in which port they want to disable

```
def disablePort(ssh):
    user_input = input("Enter the port number you want to disable\n")

    channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

    ssh.exec_command("portdisable " + user_input)

    channel.close()

    print("Port " + user_input + " " + "disabled\n")

    print("Waiting 10 seconds as instructed by the test case\n")

    time.sleep(10)
```

Now, I got 48 ports on this switch and I wish to disable them one by one. I feel like a naive solution would be to create a list where all the port names are hardcoded and iterate through each one and feed it in to the ssh.exec_command() method, but is there a more elegant/practical solution to this ? How would I be able to go about doing this ? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to connect with Paramiko first, then run something like (for cisco)

```
show interfaces status
```

and read the stdout from paramiko to get all the interfaces. You can then use that to iterate over, the first column being the names.

Once you have a list of the ports, you can loop over them one by one and disable them in the same manner. For example

```
for port in myListOfPorts:
    ssh.exec_command(f"portdisable {port}")
```

Though, you should check out Netmiko, it's a port of paramiko for network devices. https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko

Lastly, there's probably a single command to tear down all the interfaces instead of doing them one at a time.

Comment: Very helpful @MichaelRobinson